# Ensemble classifier for different features

Tags: classification, ensemble-learning

I am performing multiclass classification and am investigating the impact on performance given by different types of features. I am using SVM 1v1 classifier for each set of features separately, and now I want to try training a combined model that will make use of all the feature sets I have. What are the ways of creating such a combined model without simply dumping all the features together? My understanding is that this is similar to the idea of an ensemble model, however, I couldn't find examples of ensembles that would operate on multiple feature sets.

I should also mention, that I am looking for a out-of-box implementations or some libraries, rather than implementing the models myself.

Comment: you are not really supposed to "believe", but rather test. Many people before you believed that they understand data better than statistical analysis - and ml proved them wrong. Whatever you will end up building - fitting a model on all features combined is a must-have baseline

Comment: I have reasons for not doing that, and have edited the question correspondingly. Thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only have a 1-1 mapping between your abstract objects and some features in each of your sets - then this is actually a classical ensemble model, there is completely **no difference**. You think about your model as using multiple different feature extractors for the objects, thus

```
ABSTRACT OBJECTS  ------  FEATURES  ------ MODELS
 \____________________________/               |
    your definition of data        your definition of model
```

while typical ML approach (perspective on your approach) would be

```
ABSTRACT OBJECTS  ------  FEATURES  ------ MODELS
     |                      \_________________/         
   data                             model
```

in other words each pair (features_set, model) define **actual model**, and as you can see, with such perspective, you simply use any ensemble technique. The fact that you somehow "hand crafted" your various features sets does not change the fact, that it is just a part of modeling a function from your abstract objects (whatever they are) to actual decisions.

Comment: I see your point, could you possibly also refer me to some implementations that would allow achieving this easily rather than reimplementing the models myself?

Comment: scikit-learn allows such approach, simply your feature extractors have to be of form of its transformer objects, then you create a classifier as Pipeline object, and you are good to go.

Comment: can you tell me how to do this step in python  , i have six feature subset , for each of them i try multiple classifiers , reach to the most suitable algorithm for each one ... my question now how to combine them using ensemble classifier like bagging, adaboost, voting ,etc